# How can I pull a list of ID's from a SQL table as a comma-separated values string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to pull a list of integer IDs from a table using only records that match some criteria. For example:

```
Select ProdID From Products Where (ProdType='XYZ');
```

The catch is that I have to return it as a set of comma separated values so I can use it to select items in a multi-select list:

```
111,231,554,112
```

rather than as records.  I do not want to do this in my C# code - I'd like it to come right out of the database via a query this way.  Any ideas?

Comment: woe, great answers.  upvotes.  I didn't know how to do this.  cool.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In addition to @OMG Ponies method, you could also try this COALESCE trick from:

[Using COALESCE to Build Comma-Delimited Strings](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string)

```
declare @string nvarchar(255)

select @string = coalesce(@string + ', ', '') + cast(prodid as nvarchar(5))
from products
```

Comment: Good read: http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/04/08/coalesce-is-not-the-answer-to-string-concatentation-in-t-sql.aspx

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Thanks for the read. Good to know that there's a more reliable way to build the sting.

Comment: Neat. I've only ever had to do this the other direction, where someone has decided it's a good idea to store a list of comma-separated values in the database.

I wonder though if there's any particular benefit in doing this in SQL over array manipulation on the client?

Comment: i am using sql server , and **works** only when added this statement at end : `select @string as CommaSeparated`

Answer (score 30):

### MySQL

---

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.prodid SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM PRODUCTS t
 WHERE t.prodtype = 'XYZ'
```

### Oracle:

---

There is an excellent summary of the [available string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) on Tim Hall's site.

### SQL Server 2005+

---

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+ t.prodid
                FROM PRODUCTS t
               WHERE t.prodtype = 'XYZ'
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies - For the SQLServer case do you know if a method using coalese: select @ids = coalesce(@ids + ',', '') + convert(varchar, id) from ids would be significantly slower than your method?

Comment: Answering my own question, Rob Farley has a post addressing this http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/04/08/coalesce-is-not-the-answer-to-string-concatentation-in-t-sql.aspx

Comment: @David Hall: Using the `COALESCE` requires you to declare the variable first - `STUFF` doesn't.  Will performance compare tomorrow if I can.

Comment: +1 - I should have mentioned that this is SQL Server 2008 - sorry!

Comment: Ponies - I'd like to see that comparison!  I gave Justin the answer as it was the first one with Coalesce and I *will* be doing this in a stored procedure. Still, I'd love to see the results of your analysis.

Comment: hi , i get this error `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.` in `sql server` should i cast ?

Comment: You have to cast like this  ',' + cast(t.prodid as nvarchar(max)) @ShaijuT

Answer (score 12):

From SQL Server 2017 onwards, you can now use the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

This allows you to create the comma-separated list from within the SELECT statement (so works nicely with views). Given your example, it will become:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(ProdID, ',') 
FROM Products 
WHERE (ProdType='XYZ');
```

Answer (score 3):

For the future PostgreSQL users, please find the solution below (it is the same as @Matt Tester answered.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(cast(id as varchar), ',') from table1
where col1 = 'ABC';
```

Please note that the cast is required if the column you are selecting is not string (or varchar in database terms).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question but I'm adding an answer that applies the already-accepted answer using `COALESCE` by Justin Niessner. This application is how I would normally want to apply this technique where I'm querying a parent and I want to also have a single column which contains a comma-delimited list of child IDs.

These examples go against an `AdventureWorksLT` database as created in Azure SQL Database if you use the dropdown to select it when you provision a database. Nothing new here, just a convenient application that might help somebody.

The first query is how I'll normally use it:

```
SELECT
    SalesLT.ProductCategory.*,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+ cast(ProductID as nvarchar(10)) FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductCategoryID=SalesLT.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID ORDER BY ProductID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS ProductIDs
FROM SalesLT.ProductCategory
```

The second query shows a self-referencing use of it:

```
SELECT
    ParentCategory.*,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+ cast(child.ProductCategoryID as nvarchar(10)) FROM SalesLT.ProductCategory child WHERE child.ParentProductCategoryID=ParentCategory.ProductCategoryID ORDER BY child.ProductCategoryID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS ChildCategoryIDs
FROM SalesLT.ProductCategory ParentCategory
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT ParentProductCategoryID FROM SalesLT.ProductCategory children WHERE children.ParentProductCategoryID=ParentCategory.ProductCategoryID)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server see here: [Concatenate Values From Multiple Rows Into One Column](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#10)

Answer (score 0):

Theres a way to do it without additional functions:

```
DECLARE @Test nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @Test = @Test + ProdID + ', '
FROM Products 
WHERE (ProdType='XYZ')

SELECT @Test
```

@Test will contain a list of your IDs, although I cannot explain why this works.

Comment: I tried this version without functions but got two issues:

1. since my ProdID was an Int I had to add a cast to it
2. I always got a trailing ', ' at the end of the @Test that required to be removed