# SQL select list as comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with `INT Id` column. I need to select Ids as comma separated values in a subquery.

I tried:

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ids= COALESCE(@ids +',' ,'') + Convert(nvarchar(8), Id)
FROM TableX

SELECT @ids
```

It works but the problem is that I cannot use declared variable. Is there a way to avoid variable use?

Example:

```
SELECT Id FROM TableX
```

Result:

```
1
2
5
7
```

I want:

```
1,2,5,7
```

Comment: You can add example data and expected output?

Comment: May I ask what is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  I get the sense there may be some unnecessary gymnastics going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2105784/575376

Comment: @DMason you may be right. basically I have CTE with date ranges and for each date range I need to select a list of items. So pretty much I need to return hierarchical data from database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/575376

Comment: If it is hierarchical data, maybe selecting data FOR XML would be more appropriate?  That spins things off in a different direction, though.  Might not be workable, depending on how far along you've gotten.

Comment: @AndreiM: Could be more helpful if query returns list of items and for every item the rangeid or rangenum (two columns: ItemId, RangeId or three columns: ItemId, ItemName and RangeId) ?

Comment: If we concat items for every range at database level then on client side (C#) those lists of items should be splited (I suppose).

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 DECLARE  @query nvarchar(max)

 select @query = STUFF(  (SELECT N',' + cast( id as nvarchar)  
 from TableX 

 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')

 select  @query
```

NO variable :

```
  select   STUFF(  (SELECT N',' + cast( id as nvarchar)  
  from TableX 
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: "the problem is that I cannot use declared variable"

Comment: I add no variable case

Comment: @ErikE, he was quoting the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to put the code

```
create function dbo.csv ()
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @ids= COALESCE(@ids +',' ,'') + Convert(nvarchar(8), Id)
    FROM TableX

    return @ids
end
```

And the use the fucntion in the context that you cannot use variables

```
select  dbo.csv()
```

Regards